# Is there a way to directly access each fold in cross validation in Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-analysis

I know this question might be weird. The thing is that I have a project to let me only use Linear Regression...And I am a rookie. The data is very bad for this model, so before I use cross validation with Lasso. I get R2 score like this:

```
[ 0.56585033  0.62250232  0.25906073  0.46078607 -0.11444177  0.52783587
  0.52068463  0.73543617  0.56687063  0.18193339]
```

As you can see there is one -0.11 and one 0.18 which are very low. I want to see what happened to them. The reason is that even with Lasso, the following is the best I can get without having 0 and a great variance...

```
[0.33662216 0.50566121 0.27028283 0.47558253 0.4023398  0.26292917
 0.48559272 0.59582206 0.53425416 0.32131172]
```

Btw, there are only 150 observations with 20 features. This is the reason I use Lasso.

Or, is there anything else I can do to make this linear regression better?